# How ccan use FQL to get Photo commment' and LIKE tag?

Tags: android, facebook-fql

Any one have idea how can use FQL to get facebook album photo comments as well as total no of like tag ..i found something **commnet.get**  ..but i dont how to use.

pls let me know if any one have suggestion.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way - you can make a graph API to "ALBUM_ID?fields=likes,comments"
example: https://graph.facebook.com/99394368305?fields=likes,comments

hope this helps